# Как сделать интерактивную 3д карту в Blender и импортировать её в Threejs?

Tags: three.js, blender

Хочу сделать интерактивную 3д карту, такого типа 
http://rainforest.arkivert.no/#kart

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли такое сделать сначала в blender, отрисовать 3д карту и потом импортировать как-то ее в three js. Если да, подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: Вопрос настолько обширен, что требует разбиения на более мелкие задачи и решения их одну за другой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть платформы, упрощающие разработку таких приложений:

- [Blend4Web](https://www.blend4web.com/ru/)
- [Verdge 3D](https://www.soft8soft.com/verge3d/)
- [Armory 3D](https://armory3d.org/)

Рекомендую обратиться к одному из существующих движков, что упростит вашу работу и поможет сосредоточить внимание на функционале приложения, а не способе его реализации.